# drupal_set_message() shows a message twice when called from hook_init()

Tags: 6

Basically the issue is that `drupal_set_message()` shows a message twice on some pages, when it is called from `hook_init()`.

How can I avoid it happens?

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that the first message you see is the left-over result of a previous AJAX call, and the second message is the one you're intending to see.

To test that, open a different browser and browse to the page in question. First time round you should see the message once; when you refresh the page, and on subsequent requests, you should see it twice.

It happens because `hook_init()` is also invoked for AJAX requests, but the messages added to the session are never printed-then-cleared - so there's an extra copy of the same message in the next normal page load.

For most (all?) modern browser/server combinations you can use something like this to detect whether or not the request is from an AJAX source, and react accordingly:

```
function is_ajax_request() {
  return !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}
```

Comment: hi Clive, thanks for the answer! So according to you if  I add this in the check in hook_init - it must work, but I just checked and it is not working so here is what I wrote in hook_init:                 `if (user_is_logged_in() && !_is_ajax_request() && !have_profile()) { drupal_set_message(...) }`

Comment: Is `have_profile()` returning the expected value?

Comment: yes I was just editing my comment ... exactly

Comment: yes ... everything is working - just it is showing twice sometimes, and when I checked further - I realized that the hook_init is executing twice, because I added a dpm there

Comment: Hmmm...you can check that it's the definitely happening twice in the same request using a static: `static $foo = FALSE; if (!$foo) { $foo = TRUE; drupal_set_message('..); }`. If you only get one message from now on, then `hook_init()` is indeed being invoked twice. If not, it's that the message is being added to the session as part of another page request somehow (and usually that's AJAX)

Comment: I added static $foo = FALSE; outside hook_init and in hook init checked both for !_is_ajax_request() and !$foo ... it is invoked several times (hook_init),  but the workaround with the static variable is not working

Comment: The static var needs to go inside `hook_init()`

Comment: with the static variable it is showing far less frequently, but sometimes it is showing twice ... maybe it is in the session somehow

Comment: even inside hook_init - the message is showing twice sometimes

Comment: You could add a `watchdog('MYMODULE', 'hook_init called from path @path', array('@path' => $_GET['q']));`, then check the db log - that'll tell you what URLs are invoking `hook_init()`, should help narrow things down

Comment: when I checked this way - it is executing many many times - it is adding records that it is executed from while cropping images, js files, and maybe in some of those requests it is adding the message more than once

Comment: Sounds very likely. You can narrow it down still further by combining the watchdog and static methods. `static $foo = FALSE; if ($foo) { watchdog(...); } $foo = TRUE;`. Theoretically you should only get watchdog entries when `hook_init()` has fired at least once before in the same page build

Comment: do you know of some other hook that is executed only once per page load ? if can't find a way to fix it maybe I will just add an empty block and will add this functionality there

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to avoid the messages are repeated is setting the [`drupal_set_message()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7.x) `$repeat` parameter to `FALSE`.

```php
 drupal_set_message(t('You must validate your email address for this account before logging in via OpenID.'), 'status', FALSE);
```